# return all rows, in which at least one column contains a specific string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a legacy database with a table, which has around 80 columns. The problem is that the columns are written on German, so I can't understand them.
I need to take the id of all rows, which on a specific column there is the string "NETTO". The problem is that I don't know which is the column of all of them.
So now I wonder if I can check if any of the columns contains this string.
I thought of using "or" and spelling all columns, but it is not good solution for me( they are more than 80).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample:

```
t=# create table n(a text, i int, b text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into n values ('abc def',1,'here NETTO exists'), ('abc',2,'brutto');
INSERT 0 2
```

you can check in text representation for a row:

```
t=# select n from n;
                 n
-----------------------------------
 ("abc def",1,"here NETTO exists")
 (abc,2,brutto)
(2 rows)
```

thus your query would be like:

```
t=# select * from n where n::text like '%NETTO%';
    a    | i |         b
---------+---+-------------------
 abc def | 1 | here NETTO exists
(1 row)
```

Of course this will always SeqScan and thus suboptimal